# Can't remove controller name MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm worknig in `MVC4` where i need to redirect a user under a certain scenario to `LogOut`. I'm using the redirect in the `.js` file. But when i try to redirect the `routing` is not proper. It adds to the existing `controller` and throw me error.

//Code

// .cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var logoutUrl = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
</script>
```

//Controller:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", null);
        }
```

//.JS:

```
  window.location.href = logoutUrl;
```

When i try to redirect the user will be in page

```
/Home/Index
```

But, after redirecting it goes to

```
/Home/Account/LogOut
```

instead of `/Account/LogOut`

My routeConfig,

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

this throws me the error. But i need to remove the `Home` from the url and redirect to `Account/LogOut`.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are getting the correct url or for testing purpose just use hard-coded url 
and try once

`var logoutUrl = '/Account/LogOut';`

PS: i would have commented if i could but less reputation